# Can't change a paragraph text in javascript through DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

it changes for about a second and returns to the previous text.The "Loading..." line has to change into "hi,  Please click the next text box to see more instructions!".

I have tried it latest chrome and Edge browsers.

```js
function greetMe() {
    var yourName = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    
    info1 = "hi,  Please click the next text box to see more instructions!"
    document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = info1
}
```

```css
#myForm {
    float: left;
    width: 30%
}

#myformInfo {
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>HEllO ThERE!</h1>
         
        <div id="myForm"><form >
            <input id="textbox" placeholder="Your name">
            <button onclick="greetMe()">click!</button>
            <br><br>
            <input id=""> 
        </div></form>
        
        
        <div id="myFormSteps">
            <p id="textToChange">
                <script>var info1 = "Loading..."
                document.write(info1)
                </script>
            </p>
        
        </div>
         
         
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: I just check the snippet above. Its working fine.

Comment: yea, but it doesnt work on browser...

Comment: Refresh cache & reload page. Also check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you haven't set the type attribute for your button.  A button's default type is submit.  Try adding the attribute type="button" to your <button>.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button your form is submitting and the page is reloading - that's why it returning to its initial state. To stop this happening pass in `event` as a parameter to the function and then use that argument in the function with `preventDefault()`:

HTML

```
<button onclick="greetMe(event);">click!</button>
```

JS

```
function greetMe(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

As an aside it's better is to remove your inline JS and use an event listener instead.

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', greetMe, false);
```